# Marginpar only on first page

Tags: page-breaking, geometry

I'm writing a class for my resume and I wanted to add a paragraph to the left margin, but it should only be visible on the first page.

```
First page         n-th page
_______________   _______________
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
|   |         |   |             |
_______________   _______________
```

I tried by using the `geometry` package and resetting the left margin to normal, but the problem is, that the reset command breaks the current page and jumps to a new one. As I'm writing a class, I don't know, when the page is full, so I have to have a dynamic margin reset.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a method that allows dynamic margin resets after a page break. I hope, that somebody can help with this.

Here is an MWE, so you don't have to set up a document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry, lipsum}
\geometry{%
    verbose,%
    a4paper,%
    tmargin=25mm,%
    bmargin=25mm,%
    lmargin=25mm,%
    rmargin=20mm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    nohead,%
}

\newgeometry{
    lmargin=65mm
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Note that I'm only increasing the left margin and not setting up a real `marginmar` as I'll add content by a `tikzpicture` on that margin.

The document that results out of this code has two pages and in the code you don't know when the page break will happen, so you have the same case as I have in my class. Can you achieve a dynamic margin reset for the second page?

Comment: What about using an afterpage approach?

Comment: I now added `\afterpage{\restoregeometry}` before the `\lipsum` command. This does not work :/ (Yes, I included the `afterpage` package)

Comment: Use tikzpagenodes and and (current page marginpar area).